# How to Access User Input in MainPage.CS from a dependency service in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm writing my first Xamarin app and need some guidance.

My issue: I have a textbox located in my MainPage.XAML and MainPage.CS Files. I also have separate files that handle a dependency service for Xamarin. How can I get my Dependency Service's file to access values in the main page of the application?

The value I'm trying to access is called EmployeeID, and it stores the value that the user puts in the text field within MainPage.CS.

I tried writing a basic GetEmployeeID method in the MainPage.CS file but I can't seem to access this method within my Dependency Service's code. I'm also not sure If this is considered the best practice. Any tips would be great.

Here is my code:

I have a mainPage.XAML File as so:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="EmployeeSnapshot.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Entry x:Name="UserInput"
               Placeholder="Enter employee ID"
               PlaceholderColor="Gray"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               Margin="40, 300"/>

        <Button Text="Submit"
         Margin="-290" 
         HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
         Clicked="Submit_Button_Clicked"
        />

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And I also have a MainPage.CS file, which is the code behind file for the page above. It looks like this:

```
namespace EmployeeSnapshot
{
    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        { 
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        async void Submit_Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            string EmployeeID = UserInput.Text;
            
            PickPhoto()
        }
        
        async void PickPhoto()
        {
            Stream stream = await DependencyService.Get<IPhotoPickerService>().GetImageStreamAsync();
        }
        
        string GetEmployeeID()
        {
            //Can I use this function to access the user's input in files other than the code behind file?
            return UserInput.Text;
        }
```

Along with these two files, I'm using a dependency service. What I'm having trouble with is accessing the user input found in the textbox (this value is in mainPage.CS and mainPage.XAML.)

here is the dependency service:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PhotoPickerService))]
namespace PhotoPickerImplementation.iOS
{
    public class PhotoPickerService : IPhotoPickerService
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<Stream> taskCompletionSource;
        UIImagePickerController imagePicker;

        public Task<Stream> GetImageStreamAsync()
        {
            //Create and define UIImagePickerController
            imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController
            {
                SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary,
                MediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.AvailableMediaTypes(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary)
            };

            //Set Event Handlers
            imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia;
            imagePicker.Canceled += OnImagePickerCancelled;

            //Present UIImagePickerController

            //Return Task Object
            taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Stream>();
            return taskCompletionSource.Task;
        }

        void OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia(object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs args)
        { 
           //I need to access MainPage's textbox value for the employee ID
           //This doesn't work: string EmployeeID = EmployeeSnapshot.MainPage.GetEmployeeID();

        }
```

Comment: Why do you need the employee ID in the picker? Its only job is to select a file and return it as a stream. You need to set the `TaskCompletionSource`'s Result to get the stream in your page. If you must have the employee Id in the service, then change `GetImageStream` to accept the id, store it, and use it on `FinishedPickingMedia`.

Answer (score 0):

your service doesn't need to (and shouldn't) be concerned with UI elements on your page - that violates multiple OO principles.  Instead, pass the specific values that you need when you call your DI method

```
public class PhotoPickerService : IPhotoPickerService
{
    ...

    // create a variable to store the value
    private string EmployeeID;

    // pass it as a parameter
    public Task<Stream> GetImageStreamAsync(string EmpID = null)
    {
        // save the value
        EmployeeID = EmpID;

        ...
    }

    void OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia(object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs args)
    { 
       // when you need the value, just reference the class variable EmployeeID

    }
```

then, when you call your service, pass in the value

```
async void PickPhoto()
    {
        Stream stream = await DependencyService.Get<IPhotoPickerService>().GetImageStreamAsync(UserInput.Text);
    }
```